# Error Message: BC30451: 'RouteConfig' is not declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This afternoon I updated a ASP.NET(VB) webforms site that has not been touched in about two years.

The update was on the page EventsCalendar.aspx.vb.  I added a line to change the time format on a 3rd-party calendar app.  Here are a few lines of the code.  The line commented out is the line I added.

BEGIN CODE ----------------------------------------

```
Scheduler.Config.first_hour = 8
Scheduler.Config.last_hour = 19
Scheduler.Config.time_step = 30
'scheduler.config.hour_date = "%H:%i"
Scheduler.Config.isReadonly = True
Scheduler.Config.limit_time_select = True
```

END CODE ------------------------------------------

After uploading the EventsCalendar.aspx.vb to the website, the entire site crashed. You can see for yourself by going to http://WillowLaneCare.com

The error reads:

BEGIN ERROR ---------------------------

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'RouteConfig' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Source Error:

Line 6:  
Line 7:      Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Line 8:          RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
Line 9:          BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
Line 10:     End Sub
Source File: E:\web\willowlanec\htdocs\global.asax    Line: 8
```

END ERROR ------------------------------

You will notice the error in in the global.asax file which has not been change.

Here are the contents of the global.asax file

BEGIN GLOBAL.ASAX ----------------------

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

    Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
    End Sub

</script>
```

END GLOBAL.ASAX ----------------------

I have searched on the internet for a solution to this error.  All I can find are suggestions to Import the "System.Web.Routing" which you can see is already included in the Global.asax file.

If you do not have a suggestion to fix this error, then I need to ask the question if restoring the site from a previous back-up would solve the problem?

Comment: That one line made the site crash? And commenting it out didn't fix it?

Comment: The site has been restored to a previous version, but is still showing the same error. So the error was there before I made any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether you have a RouteConfig.vb file under App_code folder. it should be present in the folder. If not add a file called RouteConfig.vb and paste the below contents. If it's present check its protection level.

```
Imports System.Web.Routing
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls

Public Module RouteConfig
    Public Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)
        Dim settings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)
    End Sub
End Module
```